# Why doesn't this goto inside this switch work?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

For this program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var state = States.One;
        switch (state)
        {
            case States.One:
                Console.WriteLine("One");
                break;
            case States.Zero:
                goto case States.One;
        }
    }
}

public enum States : ulong
{
    Zero = 0,
    One = 1,
}
```

I got:

> "A switch expression or case label must be a bool, char, string,
>   integral, enum, or corresponding nullable type"

But `state` variable is `enum` type. The error disappears if I comment the `goto case` line.

I am using VS 2013. + .NET 4.5.1.

Comment: Compiles fine on mono with: http://www.compileonline.com/compile_csharp_online.php

Comment: IF you remove ": ulong" part, would it work?

Comment: Please, don't use `goto` it is considered a bad-practice

Comment: @Samuel - i am using vs 2013. + .net 4.5.1.

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg sometimes it is usefull and clear to not creates tens of voids for switch

Comment: This bug is fixed in Roslyn.

Comment: @BransDs The performance of a `goto` statement is slower than a normal `break` and it shouldn't be used because of it makes code more complex + it isn't the natural way for the compiler to work, being forced to a different place in code this way.

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg. It appears the OP is attempting to create a switch fall-thru which has to be done using the goto statement in C#. In C/C++ you don't need the goto for a fall-thru. Also, consider why "goto considered harmful" in the first place - it's because it can lead to spagetti code in un structured code.

Comment: @user2425056 You are right, a simple summary about goto: Goto may look faster and convenient. But it can actually confuse the runtime and result in poorer performance. In other words, goto is not only more complex for programmers, but is more difficult for the JIT compiler to optimize.

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg, Do You have a link to some reference about the poor performance of goto in C#?

Comment: I most surely wouldn't want to document the enum for all possible 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 cases you can use it with.

Comment: @user2425056 http://www.dotnetperls.com/goto there is a performance comparison in the article as well.

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg: `goto` within `switch` is only mentioned in the end of that article. It refers to a [separate article about `goto` in `switch` on the same site](http://www.dotnetperls.com/goto-switch), which starts with the explanation "Goto is used inside switch. This **can enhance performance** and reduce code size in some cases." (emphasis by myself)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper `in some cases` should be underlined and bold.

Comment: @MarcGravell Don't suppose you can tell us why it's broken? :D

Comment: @Rawling I have no clue; presumably simply a bad line of code

Comment: I think that `goto case` is probably the most-likely-to-be-valid usage of `goto` that exists in C#.

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg If you look at compiled IL, you'll see why the performance thing you said is probably incorrect. For example, these methods produce the same IL, which includes a goto-like instruction (`bge.s`, which jumps to a target instruction if `a` is greater than or equal to `b`), when compiled with optimization. http://pastebin.com/nmpJ2j8i

Comment: @BransDs I know your answer has already been answered, but you should consider reading up on "goto considered harmful", for instance here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful

Comment: I don't understand why people think this use of "goto" is a bad practice.  The same exact construct semantically works in C/C++ and no at that point says that "oh you're doing a branch which is technically a goto, so you shouldn't do that".

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This is [known bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/647709/c-compiler-cannot-handle-goto-case-with-ulong) of the C# compiler when `enum` is typed as `ulong` and you use `goto case` at the same time. If you remove the `ulong` from `enum`, it compiles just fine. And because not many people run into this problem, they are not focusing on fixing it.

Comment: It works fine with any other integral type, signed or unsigned, so I'd say it's a bug, too.

Comment: It's documented as a bug, indeed.

Comment: But you can leave ulong and just use the value in the goto with something like 'goto case 1, 'goto case 0 ... and you will see a warning The 'goto case' value is not implicitly convertible to type 'States'

Comment: @blacai Well, that can't handle values more than `int.MaxValue`. If that's not the problem we can go for it.

Comment: For the record: it has been fixed in Rosyln, so the last sentence is perhaps unfair.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on your use case, this might also be an option for you:

```
switch (state)
{
    case States.Zero:
    case States.One:
        Console.WriteLine("One");
        break;
}
```

This should be working according to an example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/06tc147t.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You could use a label for goto instead of using the `case` directly in the goto statement:

```
switch (state)
{
    case States.One:
caseZeroRedirect:
        Console.WriteLine("One");
        break;
    case States.Zero:
        CouldDoSomethingFirst();
        goto caseZeroRedirect;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:-

```
switch (state)
{
 case States.Zero:
 case States.One:
    Console.WriteLine("1");
    break;
}
```